# jQuery function that makes something occur when particular select option value is active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been having a ton of trouble making a rather simple function work and I really need a second opinion on it since it just doesn't seem to work... As you can see I am trying to have an alert come up for whenever a particular option is selected but when I select any one of them... nothing occurs. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. Here is the code I am working with!

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#contactType').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() === 'complaints'){
    alert('you have selected complaints');
  }
  else if ($(this).val() === 'technical') {
    alert('you have selected technical problems');
  }
  else if ($(this).val() === 'product') {
    alert('you have selected technical product issues');
  }
});

</script>

<p>
  <label>Please Select your reason for contactin us.
    <select name="contactType" id="contactType">
      <option value="complaints">Complaints</option>
      <option value="technical">Technical Problems</option>
      <option value="product">Product Issues</option>
    </select>
  </label>
</p>
```

It just doesn't seem to work and I've tried everything, I'm hoping it's a dumb mistake but I'm honestly stumped at this point. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: your js code is processed before the html is loaded. so there is no tag with the id `contactType` and so there is no bound change event listener

Comment: so would I put it in a $(document).ready function??? or just put the script in the footer?

Comment: Place it in the footer https://jsfiddle.net/e65c11wu/

Comment: Ask different people and you get different answers. I'm a fan of using `$(()=>...)` (it's the same as `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`)

Comment: @nodws realy xD You suggest one thing and post a fiddle that uses the other thing? That's a joke, right? :D

Comment: @nodws why would you suggest a fiddle?

Comment: both work foo ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your script tag below the HTML.

Your javascript is running prior to the html being rendered so the value's you are trying to reference do not exist yet, thus your alert will not work.

If you move the script down, below your html, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a timing problem. the javascript code is executed before the html is loaded (because it's placed above the html markup and isn't wrapped inside a load handler).

There are two solutions:
1) place the js code under the html markup:

```
<script>var foo = document.querySelector('#bar').length;</script> // foo is 0
<div id="bar"></div>

<div id="bar"></div>
<script>var foo = document.querySelector('#bar').length;</script> // foo is 1
```

2) use the ondomready event:

```
<script>window.onload = ()=>{var foo = document.querySelector('#bar').length;}</script> // foo is 1
<div id="bar"></div>
```

or with jQuery:

```
<script>$(()=>{var foo = document.querySelector('#bar').length;})</script> // foo is 1
<div id="bar"></div>
```